# Подскажите пожалуйста насчет SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

У меня есть активность в которой по завершению определенного действия я сохраняю в булеву переменную значение `true` с помощью `SharedPreferences`, для последующего прочтения в другой активности.

```
    public class Add_new_exercise extends AppCompatActivity
{


    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "app_preferences";
    public static final String STAT = "Stat";
    public boolean stat;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new_exercise);

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        Button add_new_exercise = findViewById(R.id.add_new_exercise);
        add_new_exercise.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                if (/*какое то условие*/)
                {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    stat = true;
                    editor.putBoolean(STAT, stat);
                    editor.apply();
                    finish();       //сохранили значение true
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.string.pls_add_data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

теперь я пытаюсь в другой активности получить это значение переменной из `SharedPreferences` но оно всегда `false` и вообще по моему не меняется или даже не достается из `prefs`

я для проверки просто вывожу в `TextView` состояние переменной и там всегда `false`

```
    public class Activity_2 extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("my_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);

        boolean x = prefs.getBoolean("Stat", false);

        TextView test = findViewById(R.id.test);
        test.setText(String.valueOf(x));

    }
}
```

Никак не могу понять в чем проблема, ведь в пределах одного класса активности у меня все отработано и сохраняется/достается как надо, а в другом классе получить переменную не выходит(.

Comment: Похоже, что читаете не оттуда, куда сохраняете. Имена не совпадают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) В первой активити для записи требуется:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("MY_APP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("Stat", stat);
editor.commit();
```

2) В активити, где хотите получить данные из SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("MY_APP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean stat = sharedPref.getBoolean("Stat", true);
```

---

P.S. Источник - [официальная документация](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html?hl=ru#ReadSharedPreference)

Comment: Вроде, это не будет работать, т.к. `Activity#getPreferences()` вернёт экземпляр префов, работающий только для вызвавшей его активити. Для доступа к префам из разных активити надо глобальный использовать: `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, точно. Тогда нужно юзать getSharedPreferences(). Поправил ответ

Comment: спасибо, этот способ работает, но я хочу заметить, что у меня заработало только когда я писал имя переменной куда сохранялось не "Stat" а STAT (`public static final String STAT = "Stat";`) и так везде где есть такие обращения

Comment: @Howling, ну по идее да, такие вещи правильно создавать как `public static final` в каком-нибудь классе с вашими глобальными константами